# PN2222A tranistor not working properly

Tags: transistors, logic-gates

[image: PN2222A Pin out]

I have;  pin E to LED's positive pin
- negative pin of the LED is connected to a resistor and then ground.
 - If I then leave pin C open and apply power to pin B it will turn the LED on,

It is supposed to not turn the LED on because there is no power to pin C?

This is a problem because;
 I am trying to make an AND gate by connecting,
 - the E to the C pin of another.

I am supplying power using a Arduino.

What might be my problem?

I have tried using 5v power and 3.3v power to see if I am overpowering it.

EDIT:
[image: PN2222A Pin out]
Here is my circuit. I followed the suggestion and flipped the transistor and the LED still lit up when it should not have. Any other ideas?
I also read some other questions and I think that I should not be using PN2222A transistors but instead use a 2n7000 transistor. If that is the case would this work [https://www.amazon.com/MCIGICM-2n7000-n-channel-transistor-assortment/dp/B07BKX255D/ref=sr_1_17_sspa?ie=UTF8&qid=1523501912&sr=8-17-spons&keywords=2n7000&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07BKX255D)?

Comment: Your transistor is working as a diode.  Put LED and resistor on collector side.

Comment: Draw a schematic! We are engineers, not poets, we understand drawings, not poems!

Comment: @JakubRakus Can we not be both....

Comment: Duplicate question, Justin. Just in case you do not know how to search here, see top of page. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=transistor+and+gate

Answer (score 6):

so you are using NPN transistor, as somebody mentioned it in comments you are using it as a diode.

This is the right scheme you should be using

[image: right scheme]